# Python class assignments creating a confusion

Tags: python, class

Look at the following example.

```
>>> class X:
        pass 
>>> Y = X
>>> X
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> Y
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> Y == X
True
>>> Y is X
True
```

The above code is understandable. But, look at the below one.

```
>>> X = type('X', (), {})
>>> Y = type('X', (), {})
>>> X
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> Y
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> X == Y        # Shouldn't this be True??
False
>>> X is Y
False
```

Here `X is Y == False` is as expected. But how come `X == Y` is `False`?
They both are of same class type, ain't they?

Comment: Short answer to the question: Classes can't be compared with `==` because nobody implemented that feature; and the standard behaviour of `a == b` (if not overriden) is to return `a is b`.

Comment: @Rawing Ur comment makes more sense. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `class` statement, two things happen.  First, a class is created, with the name you specify.  That is, the class has a `__name__` attribute with that string as its value.  Second, that class is assigned to that name as a variable.

```
>>> class X:
        pass 
>>> X.__name__
'X'
>>> Y = X
>>> Y.__name__
'X'
```

When you print a class, it's showing you the `__name__` value:

```
>>> X
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> Y
<class '__main__.X'>
```

As you've seen when you assign X to Y, the name of the variable, and the name of the class, can be different.

When you create classes with `type`, you make a new distinct class every time.  You can have two classes with the same `__name__`, each assigned to different variable.  That's what you did here:

```
>>> X = type('X', (), {})
>>> Y = type('X', (), {})
>>> X
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> Y
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> X.__name__
'X'
>>> Y.__name__
'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#type): '... With three arguments, return a new type object'.

```
>>> X1 = type('X', (), {})
>>> Y1 = type('X', (), {})
>>> id(X1) == id(Y1)
False
```

Whereas the first example Y 'references' X:

```
>>> class X:
...     pass
... 
>>> Y = X
>>> id(X) == id(Y)
True
```